# Add a new reason to reject suggest edits: "This should be a comment"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, rejection-reasons

I think it would be useful to have a reject reason "This should be a comment".

Whenever I see (minor) edits to code or some edit that challenges the opinion in the original post I select "other" and write "This should be a comment".

My reasoning behind is to reject the edit but to give the editor a hint what he should have done.

Recent example:
https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/317430

Changed

```
if aline[0] in m.keys():
```

to

```
if aline[0] in m
```

A comment would have been a better option compared to a straight edit.

Comment: At least on ELU we have "invalid edit" which includes "this is an attempt to reply to this post"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This already does exist:

> **invalid edit**
>   This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

Comment: you're right :) somehow I always just read it as : this edit is incorrect (i.e. the content is invalid or false).